# How to get Boot_Complete intent in HTC when i use 'poweroff' for reboot?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to start service once i get BOOT_COMPLETE intent. In HTC explorer there are 2 options for reboot those are 'poweroff' and 'restart'. When i use 'restart' i am getting BOOT_COMPLETE intent properly. But when i use 'poweroff' not getting BOOT_COMPLETE intent so i am not able to start service. Is their any intent i can get only after reboot in HTC?

I have been surfing Google, could not find any hint. I am stuck please help me out

I used this code `<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>` in manifest but no use

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the whole receiver section of your manifest and the code you use in the receiver.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some HTC devices can enable a "fast boot" feature that is more like a deep hibernation and not a real reboot and therefore should not give the BOOT_COMPLETE intent. Also make sure that the app is not installed on the SD card as it might not receive the BOOT_COMPLETED because of that.

This might also be interesting:

http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/13/boot-completed-regression-confirmed.html

http://arthurfmay.blogspot.jp/2011/06/broadcastreceiver-bootcompleted-and.html

And especially this where the "fast boot" option is being mentioned:

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/56562e4de4919dc6

Edit:

How about simply using:

```
Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON
```

And you can then check if the service is running:

```
public static boolean ServiceRunning(Context cx) 
{   ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) cx.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE))
    {   if ("<<<service name goes here>>>".equals(service.service.getClassName()))
        {   return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And if it isn't just start it:

```
public static void ServiceCheck(Context cx)
{   if(ServiceRunning(cx) == false)
    {   Intent svc = new Intent(".<<<Servicename>>>");
        cx.startService(svc);
        Log.i("Service-Check","Service Starting");
    }
    else
    {   Log.i("Service-Check","Service Existing");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I unchecked 'fast boot' option now i am getting Boot_complete intent. But i need one more thing how to get Boot_Complete with out disabling the 'fast boot' option in HTC desire.