# Android Broadcast Receiver not Working (Boot Complete)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to start `BroadcastReceiever` on installation of my application. I found some Thread over stackoverflow that this could be done by using Boot Complete BroadCastReceiever.

But After writing code we could not get success because my receiver did not call at all.

Manifest File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.broadcastdemo"

    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />




    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.broadcastdemo.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >


            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            >
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.example.broadcastdemo.BootReceiver"  
            android:enabled="true"
             android:exported="false" 
            >`


`
  <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please upload your code

Comment: You have to start your application at least once until your broadcast receiver get registered! explained in detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46294732/5024937

Answer (score 1):

Did you `register` the `receiver` in `manifest.xml`

```
<receiver
            android:name="YOUR_ACTION_STRING.BootCompletedReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```