# Android service can‘t restart while the mobile phone reboot.

Tags: android, boot

I'm trying to restart the service in my App while the mobile phone reboot.My `BOOT_COMPLETED` receiver is called and the service can restart successfully in most of the Android phone but the MIUI V5 system.
This system forbid the Apps to receive the `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast without it's permission.How can i restart the service in another way?

Comment: this post may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20441308/boot-completed-not-working-android

Comment: Do you try another Broadcast like SCREEN_ON ? Maybe it's also fired when the phone startup

Comment: Yes.I had try all the Broadcasts ,but it doesn't work.