# Android notification app not working properly

Tags: java, android, notifications, alarmmanager, android-notifications

I'm developing an android app, and part of it involves a notification that reminds the user to do something. This notification at a specified time and repeats every 12 hours. I'm using `AlarmManager` to schedule the alarm and I've also included the code to start my Alarm Service when the device boots. Here are my java classes:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    int i = preferences.getInt("numberoflaunches", 1);

    if (i < 2) {
        alarmMethod();
        i++;
        editor.putInt("numberoflaunches", i);
        editor.commit();
    }
}

private void alarmMethod() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmService.class);
    this.startService(intent);

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Alarm Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

}
```

AlarmService.java

```
public class AlarmService extends Service {

//used for register alarm manager
PendingIntent pendingIntent;
//used to store running alarm manager instance
AlarmManager alarmMgr;
//Callback function for alarm manager event
BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

private static final String TAG = "MyService";

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    //Register AlarmManager Broadcast receive.
    RegisterAlarmBroadcast();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 6);

    alarmMgr.cancel(pendingIntent);
    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 60 * 12, pendingIntent);

}

private void showNotification() {

    Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("app_name")
            .setContentText("something")
            .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
            .setSound(soundUri)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .build();

    NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(0, notification);

}

private void RegisterAlarmBroadcast() {
    Log.i("RegisterAlarmBroadcast", "Register Intent.RegisterAlarmBroadcast");

    //This is the call back function(BroadcastReceiver) which will be called when your alarm time is reached.
    mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        private static final String TAG = "Alarm Example Receiver";

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.i(TAG, "BroadcastReceiver::OnReceive() >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
            showNotification();
        }
    };

    //Register the alarm broadcast here
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.example.application.myNotification"));
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent("com.example.application.myNotification"), 0);
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) (this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE));
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
}

}
```

autostart.java

```
public class autostart extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(arg0,AlarmService.class);
    arg0.startService(intent);
    Log.i("Autostart", "started");
}
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.application" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".autostart">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service
        android:name=".AlarmService"
        android:enabled="true" />
</application>
```

However I must have done something wrong as it is not working properly. My problems are:
1. When I exit the app, the notification for some reason goes off, whatever the time is.
2.  When I reboot, the notification goes off, whatever the time is.

I don't know if these problems are in any way related, maybe I have a piece of code that's messing everything up. But either way I would really appreciate any sort of help I can get. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would check this `onStartCommand` and `startForeground` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html and . Whenever I start a Service without startForeground I lost it and stops doing its job. In the BroadcastReceiver you don't seem to be overriding the `onReceive` method (you forgot the @Override annotation), check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20441308/boot-completed-not-working-android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repeating interval should be 24 hours (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24), not 12 hours.

You are individually setting the time to 6 AM. So you can remove the line `calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());`

EDIT:

I have made some of modifications to your code and finally got it working.

You problem was that you set an alarm for 6:00 AM. But you are setting this alarm at a time after 6:00 AM (say 9:00 AM). That is, you are setting an alarm for a past time. So it will go off immediately.

I made a work around for this. If the time you need to set alarm is past, set the alarm to trigger on the next day.

This is my modified code.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        int i = preferences.getInt("numberoflaunches", 1);

        if (i < 2) {
            alarmMethod();
            i++;
            editor.putInt("numberoflaunches", i);
            editor.commit();
        }
    }

    private void alarmMethod() {

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                new Intent("com.example.application.myNotification"),
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) (this
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE));

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 6);

        long mills = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
        if (mills <= System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            Calendar c1 = calendar;
            c1.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            mills = c1.getTimeInMillis();
        } else {
            mills = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
        }

        alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, mills,
                1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, pendingIntent);

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Alarm Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();

    }

}
```

Autostart.java

```
public class Autostart extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1)
    {
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(arg0, 0, new Intent("com.example.application.myNotification"), 0);
        AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) (arg0.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE));

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 6);

        long mills = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
        if (mills <= System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            Calendar c1 = calendar;
            c1.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            mills = c1.getTimeInMillis();
        } else {
            mills = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
        }

        alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, mills, 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, pendingIntent);

        Log.i("Autostart", "started");
    }

}
```

Alarmer.java

```
public class Alarmer extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        showNotification(context);
    }

    private void showNotification(Context context) {

        Random r = new Random();
        int r0 = r.nextInt();

        Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager
                .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle("app_name")
                .setContentText("something" + r0)
                .setContentIntent(
                        PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context,
                                MainActivity.class),
                                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
                .setSound(soundUri).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setAutoCancel(true).setOnlyAlertOnce(true).build();

        // NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(0, notification);
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


        nm.notify(r0, notification);

    }

}
```

AndroiManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.alarmtest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".autostart" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name=".Alarmer" android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.application.myNotification" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".AlarmService"
            android:enabled="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Compare it with your code and make changes.

Comment: That didn't work, but I did find a solution to this problem. I got rid of `Calendar.AM_PM` and used the 24-hour format instead of the 12-hour format for the `HOUR_OF_DAY` (e.i. 10 PM will be 22). The notification now comes up only in that hour. But thanks for the heads up about the `calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());`. Any ideas on how to solve the other problems? Again any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Which are the problems that still persist?

Comment: I've updated it and left the two problems I still have.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfectly, and I really appreciate your help. One last question though, if I wanted this notification to go off twice a day, once at 6 am and once at 6 pm, what would be the best way to do so? Because if I restarted the phone, the repeat command (which I would set to 12 hours) wouldn't be working until the specified time is reached.

Comment: I suggest you set two alarms one for 6 am and one for 6 pm. Its easier to work with two alarms.

Comment: Ah okay, so I would have two alarms each set to repeat every 24 hours. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: hi,this is a optional name ->`com.example.application.myNotification`

Comment: Yes it can be any name.