# Trigger an activity if the clock is match

Tags: android

I want to start an activity if the clock is 15.00. Is there any reference ?

Assuming i had running services in my background.

**EDIT**
I have value from database. Then the activity will trigger based on clock that i saved from database. So if the database has values like 01.00 , 13.00 , 22.30 then the activity will start when the phone clock match as that 3 value.

Comment: Do you want to repeat it daily?

Comment: Hi.. please check above. I had already edit the post

Answer (score 0):

You can use an AlarmManager for that

Answer (score 0):

This post will help you. Use `AlarmManager` to set a repeating alarm. The time can be set.

[Android notification app not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30489474/android-notification-app-not-working-properly/30490629#30490629)