# Intent BOOT_COMPLETED not working on Huawei device

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, bootcompleted, huawei-mobile-services

I want to listen to APN Changes in my Android App.

Therefore I start a Service on `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`.
This Service starts a ContentObserver which listens to changes to 
`content://telephony/carriers/preferapn`.

I tested this setup on a few different devices (e.g. LG Spirit with Android 5.0, Samsung A3 with 6.0, Emulator Nexus5 with 7.0 and Huawei P9 Lite with 7.0)

On the Huawei phone `onCreate` of my Service is not called.

My other approach with `android.intent.action.ANY_DATA_STATE` in combination with a `BroadcastReceiver` which is registerd in the Manifest doesn't work either on this phone.

relevant parts of my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>  

...

<receiver android:name=".ConnectivityChangeReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ANY_DATA_STATE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<receiver android:name=".APNChangedServiceStarter" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service android:name=".APNChangedService"></service>
```

Comment: did it work on samsung??

Comment: both approaches worked on all mentioned devices/emulators except the huawei phone

Comment: did u turn off fast boot mode on huwaei phone??

Comment: in huawei devices you have to whitelist your apps on the "telephony manager". You need to whitelist it on autostart and on energy manager. Also, the app has to be opened once before it works. This is absolutely disgusting and you can´t do anything against, only inform your users about in your app. I faced this many times on huawei devices and it takes long time before I find this solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BOOT\_COMPLETED not working Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20441308/boot-completed-not-working-android)

Comment: @Opiatefuchs i can't even see the option in the telephony manger to enable auto-start for my app and installing the additional app `PM Plus` from Huawei which should enable this option fails.

Comment: open the telephony manager and swipe from right to left at the bottom menu. Then comes the auto start...

Comment: yeah i can swipe but there is no `auto start` :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Huawei Phones have a built-in startup manager, it could be that the app is not yet enabled.

[image: from https://www.isunshare.com/android/how-to-control-startup-apps-on-huawei-android.html]

Go to Settings > All, and choose Startup manager.
This program is used to manage startup apps on Android phone.
Allow or disallow app to run automatically after the Huawei phone starts up.

Comment: i don't have that mentioned option in my phonemanager and when i follow the description from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIPxTlJOT38 i can't intall the mentioned app `PM Plus` to enable this settings. Anyway: This might be a solution for us but will never be a reliable solution for end-users.

Comment: there is no solution for the user, only information. This is something Huawei is to blame for, but the user doesn´t understand and maybe blames your app...

Comment: On Huawei Mate 10 pro, running Pie do: Settings -> Battery -> App launch -> Disable automatic management for your app

Comment: @Arkady, this is the most relevant answer to date, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 10):

Just for an update, Huawei changed the menu path in the Android 9 version.
On Huawei Mate 10 pro the way to get to this menu:
Settings -> Battery -> App launch -> Disable automatic management for your app.

A pop-up will appear, asking what you want to allow (all true by default). make sure that the first, Auto-launch is enabled