# Android BOOT_COMPLETED not received in Huawei device

Tags: android, intentfilter, alarm, reboot, huawei-mobile-services

I am currently working on a reminder app and the **BootReceiver** is not executed when the **Huawei** device is rebooted. I have tested the app in other android devices and it works perfectly, except for **Huawei** specific devices. I have tried the following.

> **Manifest file**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

<receiver
    android:name=".BootService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

> **BootService class**

```
public class BootService extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "BootService Lumea";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Boot Completed Received: " + intent);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Boot Completed Received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Would be really helpful if you guys can help me find a solution for the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intent BOOT\_COMPLETED not working on Huawei device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43913937/intent-boot-completed-not-working-on-huawei-device)

Comment: No not really since I am looking for a solution such that the user does not exit the app and manually changes the settings.

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41791150/7948109) help?

Comment: You'll have this problem on all Chinese phones I haven't found a solution for this yet :((

Comment: This requires, the user to explicitly change the settings for the app. I am looking for a solution where we can programmatically whitelist the app, without any user interaction in settings.

Comment: Keep an eye out for a solution on https://dontkillmyapp.com/huawei . It gets updated whenever there's something available to do either programmatically or by prompting the user to change some settings.

Answer (score 1):

On Huawei and Honor smartphones, the user must independently give permission for autorun after reboot. Settings->Battery->(your app)->Autorun settings->Automatic control uncheck the box.
I understand that your question is old, and you have most likely already solved the problem. But I'm posting this for the rest of the people, as the solution to the problem is very implicit.

Answer (score 0):

There is no doubt that there is a system broadcast in the behavior of power on. The idea is that we can register a broadcast in our code, and it's basically a static broadcast to do this. Here's a sample code. Let's inherit a broadcastreceiver and find a fixed action, that is, get the android.intent.action .BOOT_ Completed, make a logical judgment in it.
Here is skill link 
https://blog.csdn.net/u011174639/article/details/106120684?utm_medium=distribute.pc_relevant.none-task-blog-baidujs-1