# App not receiving boot completed intent in some devices

Tags: java, android

i created an app that always start a service once the device has completed booting. 
This is the Manifest code..

```
<receiver>
 android:name="StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver"
 android:directBootAware ="true"
 android:enabled="true"
 android:exported="true">

    <intent-filter>

        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />

    </intent-filter>

</receiver>
```

The service always start in some devices once boot is completed but in my own device which is running android 7.0, the boot completed service doesn't start unless i convert the app to system app using root access.  Can someone tell me how to make the app to start the  service on boot completed without converting it to a system app?

Comment: Which device are you using?

Comment: My device is Infinix Hot5

Comment: Other installed apps normally start at boot completion but my app doesn't start

Comment: add **RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED**

Answer (score 0):

First of All

> receiver android:name="StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver"

Your **path to Receiver** should written over here for example:

```
<receiver android:name=".receiver.BootReceiver">
```

first dot suggest your path till root of the package.

Create a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) and register it to receive [ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED). You also need [RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED) permission.

Read: [Listening For and Broadcasting Global Messages](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#system-broadcasts) , and [Setting Alarms](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms)

Answer (score 0):

Try into manifest

```
 <receiver
        android:name=".AutoStart"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="500" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Make sure also to include the completed boot permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

Also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46294732/3514144) answer carefully