# How to detect BOOT_COMPLETED in andorid 9 and above in Oneplus and Xiaomi devices and other chinese roms (api level 28+)

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest, bootcompleted

I have been trying to launch my app after boot completed, but somehow it works on virtual devices but not working on real devices. It is working on from till android 8 but not from android 9 in devices like Xiaomi, Oneplus and Realme. I have read the documents, it was stated that developers can still use receive_boot_completed. I am not able to solve this problem any help will be appreciated.

**Manifest File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.restartexample">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name=".RestartReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**RestartReceiver:**

```
public class RestartReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static String TAG = RestartReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("Receiver","onReceive");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Action: " + intent.getAction() + "\n");
        sb.append("URI: " + intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME).toString() + "\n");
        String log = sb.toString();
        Log.d(TAG, log);
        Toast.makeText(context, log, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BOOT\_COMPLETED not working Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20441308/boot-completed-not-working-android)

Comment: no, i have already tried that way check my codes!

Comment: i am have tried this app on samsung m30s having android 9 its not working