# For loop is not executed after calling BOOT_COMPLETED

Tags: android, for-loop, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, bootcompleted

### BootReceiver.kt

```
override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    if (intent.action == Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) {
        for (i in 0 .. 10) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "number $i", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            Thread.sleep(1000)
        }
    }
}
```

### Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application>

    <receiver android:name=".BootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

If the mobile phone is rebooted in the above code, the for loop does not run. By any chance, when ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED inside the onReceive() function, when I just opened Toast, it was executed.

#### ex)

```
if (intent.action == Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Reboot", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Why is the for statement not executed?? How can I execute the for statement?? If you look at the code, the reason for putting `Thread.sleep(1000)` is that Toast might pass too quickly. For reference, removing `Thread.sleep(1000)` did not execute the for statement.

Comment: is it working without             Thread.sleep(1000) ?

Comment: Even without ```Thread.sleep(1000)``` the for statement doesn't work.

Comment: may be this method it self it not getting called.. try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20441308/boot-completed-not-working-android

Comment: Thank you for your advice. After ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED, startService was started, but ```Emulator: qemu: unsupported keyboard cmd=0x84``` error occurs and the service is not running.