# BootReceiver not starting on boot

Tags: java, android

I know this question has been asked way to many times but I am going to have to ask if again, because after looking at every question and example I could find it still doesn't work.

I need to do something when the user restarts their devices. So I setup a receiver, but it doesn't work and I don't know why? Please help. Thanks in advance.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />`

```
        <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name="com.test.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        
        <receiver android:name=".rebootReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/> 
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
```

```
package com.testapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.widget.Toast; 

public class rebootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Toast.makeText(context, "It's working!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
 
            Toast.makeText(context, "It's really working!!!!!" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            
        }
    }
   
 
}
```

Comment: Have you checked this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20441308/boot-completed-not-working-android)

Comment: Yes, but I looked over it again and tried a few things. It still doesn't work.