# How to run code on device boot in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to run a piece of dart code when the android device boots up. Ideally, the code should run immediately or with a small delay (1-2 minutes at most). I don't want the app to start up, just a headless piece of code to run.

**My Use Case**:

I am working on an alarm clock application, and I want to handle the alarms that go off when the device is turned off, like disabling one-time alarms, and scheduling the next alarm if it's a repeat alarm. I can't afford to wait for long to handle these cases in case a repeat alarm was scheduled to ring shortly after the user boots up the device.

**What I Have Tried**:

I have tried doing it with [flutter_background_fetch](https://github.com/transistorsoft/flutter_background_fetch), with `headless: true` and `startOnBoot: true`. But it runs the code at 15 minutes intervals, which is too long for my use case, as explained above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally figured it out. I first found this great article, [Initiating calls to Dart from the native side in the background](https://medium.com/@chetan882777/initiating-calls-to-dart-from-the-native-side-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugin-7d46aed32c47), detailing how to call dart code from native side while the app was in the background. This was only one piece of the puzzle though, as I had to figure out how to do so from a `BroadcastReceiver`. Luckily, I realized that [android_alarm_manager_plus](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/tree/main/packages/android_alarm_manager_plus) did something similar. So using code from those two resources, I managed to get it working.

The code is available at [flutter_boot_receiver](https://github.com/AhsanSarwar45/flutter_boot_receiver) along with the instructions on how to use it.

#### Details on how it works

1. Sends a dart callback handle to the native side, where it gets stored in the `SharedPreferences`.
2. Specifies a `BootReceiver`, which listens for the `BOOT_COMPLETED` event. This event is fired by the android system whenever the device boots.
3. When the `BootReceiver` receives the event, it starts a `JobIntentService`.
4. The service creates a background `FlutterEngine` and a method channel to communicate with the dart code.
5. It then retrieves the dart callback handle from the `SharedPreferences` and sends it to the dart side via the method channel.
6. The dart side then retrieves the callback from the handle and then calls it.

#### Notes

1. The callback runs in an isolate, so can't access data initialized in your main dart isolate. You can use dart packages/plugins though. Just be sure to initialize them in the isolate if necessary.
2. Some device might not receive the `BOOT_COMPLETED` event. You can find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20441308/how-to-fix-boot-completed-not-working-android). Consider creating an issue in the repo if that is the case.